# Orchard CMS premium themes

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

I am planning to use Orchard CMS as a base for several web sites and would like to have wide chose of themes. The ones in gallery are not bad, but I would like something different. Can you please tell me are there any places I get purchase any themes and widgets/modules.

Comment: To my knowledge there aren't any (yet). What I do is take a WordPress theme and modify it so it works in my Orchard site. Takes some designing and development skills, but it's fairly easy. I do hope someone else has an answer with a feed to some theming site.

Comment: I am working on launching a premium Orchard theme service called [Shovel & Rake](http://shovelandrake.com).
Also [Orchard Prime](http://orchardprime.com) launched recently. And as stated below, [Bind](http://bind.pt) offers Orchard themes. Those are all I know of.

Comment: Here is a direct link for orchard themes from Bind (bindtuning - new website) http://bindtuning.com/cms/orchard/themes

Answer (score 6):

I think there are some really nice templates at [Bind.pt](http://bind.pt). They also allow you to design/make changes to the template on the page, and then simply order it - and the pricing is very competitive.

The send you the package, and you can either upload it or if you choose unzip it and customize it further.

Hope this helps

Comment: There are only a small selection, but those they have a generally quite good and incredibly cheap. They are also customisable in terms of their colour scheme, before purchase.

Comment: Here is a direct link for orchard themes from Bind (bindtuning - new website) http://bindtuning.com/cms/orchard/themes